# Is this extension a Hilbert space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{F}$.

Let $H$ be a complete subspace of of $V$ and $x\in V\setminus H$

Define $K= span(H\cup \{x\})$.

Is $K$ a Hilbert space? How do I prove it?

Comment: Is your question just if it is complete?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes

Comment: Yes, it is complete.

Comment: @Behaviour How do I prove it?? Let $\{a_n\}$ be a cauchy sequence in $K$ and $\beta$ be a basis for $H$ so that $\beta\cup\{x\}$ is a basis for $K$. Let $a_n=c_1v_1+...+c_mv_m$ (unique representation by basis). I tried to remove the $x$-term, but I dunno how.. If $H$ is finite-dimensional, i can easily remove the $x$-term, but in general how??

Comment: $K=sp(H)\oplus sp({x})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = x_1 + x_2$ with $x_1 \in H$ and $x_2 \in H^\bot$ (why do these exist?).

Then you can assume w.l.o.g. that $x= x_2$ (why?).

From there you should be able to show that if $(h_n + \alpha_n x)_n$ is Cauchy, then $(h_n)_n$ and $(\alpha_n)_n$ are both Cauchy (at least if $x \neq 0$, but this follows from $x\notin H$), which should help you.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know that for a complete subspace $H$ of $V$, $V=H\oplus H^\perp$. Now I have proven that $V=H\oplus H^\perp$ and "for mutually orthogonal complete subspaces $H_1,H_2$, $H_1\oplus H_2$ is complete" and the question i asked is a corollary of this theorem.